# mysql-connector strange behaviour in Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I am trying to deploy an app with tomcat.Everything works fine, except that i expected to have an error after deleting the connector file(mysql-connector-java-5.1.40) from the WEB-INF>lib directory, but,surprise, is still working without it. So, my question is if Tomcat is saving the conector elsewhere(i ve searched in Tomcat directories and found nothing). To start the Tomcat i use the startup.bat from bin directory of Tomcat.
My simple code for mysql db connection:

```
public void jspInit() throws JSPException{
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","");
            pst.con.prepareStatement("insert into employee values(?,?,?)");
        }
        catch(Exception e{
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: and where you searched exactly?

Comment: All the possible directories...under Apache Tomcat 8.0.27/ , netbeans and so on.

Comment: and do you have another webapp using the same datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you left Tomcat running as you deleted the MySQL driver jar, Tomcat will nevertheless have the Java bytecode for it loaded in the JVM.  Did you restart Tomcat when you deleted the jar?

**UPDATE**

Look for...

- A copy of the JDBC driver jar in some shared classpath location, *e.g.* Tomcat/shared/lib
- A second copy of the JDBC driver jar (with a different name) in your webapp
- Do you perhaps have a `CLASSPATH` environment variable set on this machine?  Perhaps from another project?

Comment: Yes, that is strange...:)

Comment: What do you mean?  Was that response helpful?  Or do you have more info to provide?

Comment: Sorry, i wasn t clear. I ve restarted the server, and is stil working without the connector. I ve tried multiple browsers.

Comment: I ve deleted all the other projects(even if i didnt find the file there) and after restarting Tomcat is working as supposed. "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"- So, i guess Tomcat is saving the file in a temporary hidden directory, that i am not aware of. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `jmap -histo <PID>` if you have jmap on your system to make sure your have MySQL driver class actually loaded .

While your application is running you can also try something like `lsof |grep ".*mysql.*jar"` to see if there's a jar but remember you could have sources somewhere too.  (in that case just grep  or `find`it )